# Php header() User Agent Change

Tags: php, header, user-agent

```
$file_name = $_GET['title'];
$file_url = $_GET['url'] . $file_name;
header('Content-Type: video/octet-stream');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary"); 
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\""); 
readfile($file_url);
exit;
```

I'm using this code to download files in my site fetching from another websites.

It works if my url looks like:-

```
https://www.example.com/video_download.php?title=video.mp4&url=http://googlevideo.com/video/download/223689/289048
```

**(example)**

So, it starts downloading by fetching the video file from `http://www.googlevideo.com/video/play/221589` to my site.

But my problem is that the file can be accessed if the person uses a PC.

Can I change the User Agent by using header()?
Is it possible?
So if I change the user agent into a PC user agent, so it can be downloaded from a mobile!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but the User Agent has nothing to do with readfile() function. Readfile() will just throw the raw file input into your browser. Useful for e.g. rendering images through PHP to the client without having to expose the real file name.

Indeed, it is possible to render video to the client with readfile(), but using a HTML5 video tag will dramatically improve performance. This will also provide better mobile support.

Hope this helps you,

Comment: Can I use another code to be working the same? And also user-agent can be changed!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stream_compy_to_stream`

```
$video = fopen($file_url);
$file = fopen('videos/' . $title . '.mp4', 'w');
stream_copy_to_stream($video, $file); //copy it to the file
fclose($video);
fclose($file);
```

I wrote a class for downloading youtube video files. you can find it [here](https://github.com/smoqadam/tg-bot-youtube-downloader/blob/master/libs/Youtube.php).